# Where is t-distribution used in t-SNE?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, t-distribution, tsne

I am trying to learn the dimensionality reduction using t-SNE technique. After some videos and explanation I understood the idea behind it.
But I am not getting where the t-distribution is used behind the scenes of implementing t-SNE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, what t-SNE do is:

First, create a probability distribution over pairs high-dimensional object.

Second, from all of those distributions, they map object into a low-dimensional space. At this step, similar objects are mapped closer together, obeying the t-distribution.

The original SNE they don't use t-distribution in the second step. The author of t-SNE stated that, by using t-distribution, the less similar pair are penalized less heavily on the lower-dimensional embedding.